# SWIFT if statement and segue

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have a problem with if statement and segue
can I make a connection between them !
I have an array of these states `["Florida","NY"]()`

my idea, for example, if I clicked `"Florida"<(this is "string")` on table view 
I want the segue moves me from this table view to another table view

and if I clicked `"NewYork"` on tableView I want the segue moves me from this table view to another that has information about `NY`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
class SelectCityViewController : UITableViewController {

    // store a reference to use in transition
    var selectedCity : String?

    let cities : [String] = ["New York", "San Francisco", "Los Angeles"]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = //TODO: your implementation here

        cell.textLabel?.text = cities[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.selectedCity = cities[indexPath.row]

        performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER", nil)

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.cities.count
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? CityDetailViewController {

            vc.selectedCity = self.selectedCity!
        }
    }
}
```

Then your second view controller would have a variable with your selected city stored in it so you could setup your content accordingly

```
class SelectedCityDetailViewController : UITableViewController {

    // Set during the segue
    var selectedCity : String!

    // The rest of your methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  do something like this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

if let text = currentCell.textLabel?.text {
if text == "Florida"{
    // segue tableview controller
} else if text == "NY" {
   //another segue
  }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a viewController and add a tableView. Add two another view controllers, one for the NY info and the other containing one more uiTableView. Create two segues from main controller to the other two. Name the segues so that you can refer to them in the code. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath add the following Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

if indexPath.row == 0{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("florida", sender: nil)

    }else if indexPath.row == 1{

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ny", sender: nil)

    }
}
```

Please check this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwftp_LIDNUQSTdYU3ZNeS1HN0U/view?usp=sharing). I have created a demo project for you. I think you are a starter to the iOS development. Carry On!! :)

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I had created a demo project for this answer. I don't think so there was anything to explain it in. It was just a static demo.

Comment: Links die making them worthless. I have no issue with the link, but you should provide the key points in your answer text

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers.

Comment: I have added the description as well. And moreover this is my personal google drive's link that won't expire. Let others find there answers, why you people keep criticising others????